# Image export and import incoherence in mathematica

Tags: image, import, export, wolfram-mathematica

Happy for the incoming new year, everyone!

I run the following code in Mathematica 11 but I cannot understand the output. **b and b1 are of the same size and look the same when shown in characters, but Mathematica regards them differently.** Could you give me some advice on why this happens?

```
a = Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"];
b = ExportString[a, "PNG"];
c = ImportString[b, "PNG"];
Export["D:/flower.txt", b];
b1 = Import["D:/flower.txt"];
ByteCount /@ {b, b1}
b == b1
```

Best regards!

Comment: i suspect there are integer-float (and back) conversions going on here with some rounding error.

Answer (score 4):

To export to text you need `b` in string form.  Converting to PNG *and* Base64 works.

```
a = Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"];
b = ExportString[a, {"Base64", "PNG"}]
c = ImportString[b, {"Base64", "PNG"}]
Export["D:/flower.txt", b, "String"];
b1 = Import["D:/flower.txt", "String"];
ByteCount /@ {b, b1}
b == b1
```

> ```
> {41016, 41016}
> True
> ```

Happy New Year!